# Why will mothers smile when infants quarter'd with the hands of war?

Tags: meaning, shakespeare

From **Julius Caesar** (by Shakespeare)

> **Anthony** : Blood and destruction shall be so in use,
>          And dreadful objects so familiar,
>          **That mothers shall but smile when they behold**
>          **Their infants quarter'd with the hands of war;**
>          All pity choked with custom of fell deeds,
>          And Caesar's spirit ranging for revenge **(3.1.7)**

Why would mothers smile when they behold their dead infants?

Comment: It's answered in the first line of your quote: "Blood and destruction shall be so in use," meaning so everyday and common. To answer what is probably your REAL question: no, there is probably no amount of violence that would cause mothers to literally have this reaction; it is a visceral, horrifyingly exaggerated image.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "And Caesar's spirit ranging for revenge" is a misrendering of "And Caesar's spirit **raging** for revenge".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the interpretation of literature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anthony is saying that there will be so much violence that it will seem commonplace (*so in use* and *so familiar*). People will be so used to the sight of violence that they will become immune to it. Even mothers will only smile when their infants are butchered (instead of the real torment and grief they would naturally feel).

It's exaggeration for effect rather than a real observation.

Comment: Immune to violence: "All pity choked with custom of fell deeds"